# Using a full stop instead of a question mark at the end of a question

Tags: inversion

> Voulez-vous, pour commencer, fermer votre livre et écouter deux ou trois fois l'enregistrement de ce texte.

I thought "Voulez-vous" was a way to start a question, "Would you like..?", but there's no question mark at the end of the sentence so it can't be a question here. What does it mean or signify here?

For the records, I'm sure the question mark isn't droped out of style as it's used in the following sentence when another question is asked.

Comment: Will you please stop chewing gum in class. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a kind of rhetorical question which is in fact a soft order.

The full stop shows that the person speaking uses neither an interrogative tone nor an exclamative one.